# How to have bullets in my Javascript game

Tags: javascript

I am creating a game that is run in the browser(with an index.html file that uses my script file), where a spaceship shoots falling asteroids. As of now I have an array of Asteroids that fall from the top of screen and when their y value becomes greater than that of my background image, they then go back to the top.. this continues indefinitely.

```
var ctx;
var timer = timer;

var x = 285;
var y = 394;
var radius = 25;
var dx=0;
var dy=0;



var asteroidImg = new Image();
asteroidImg.src = "images/asteroid.png";

function Asteroid(){
    this.x=Math.random()*600;
    this.y=Math.random()*600;
    this.radius = 10;
    this.dy=Math.random()*3+3;
    this.dx=0;
    this.move = function(){
        this.x= this.x + this.dx;
        this.y= this.y +this.dy;

        if(this.y>411){this.y = this.y=0.;}

    };
    this.drawAsteroid = function (){
        ctx.drawImage(asteroidImg,this.x,this.y);
    };
}

var asteroids = [];
var astNumber = 10;
for(var i = 0; i< astNumber; i++)
    asteroids[i]=new Asteroid();

function drawAsteroids(asteroids){
    for(var i = 0; i< astNumber; i++){
        asteroids[i].drawAsteroid();
    }
}

var backgroundImg = new Image();
backgroundImg.src = "images/background.png";


var shipImg = new Image();
shipImg.src = "images/ship.png";



function drawShip(x,y){
    ctx.drawImage(shipImg,this.x, this.y);
}

function drawBackground(){
    ctx.drawImage(backgroundImg,0,0);
}


function draw(){
    drawBackground();
    drawShip(x,y);
    drawAsteroids(asteroids);
}

function collision(asteroid){
    if(Math.pow((asteroid.x-x) ,2)+Math.pow((asteroid.y-y) ,2)<Math.pow((asteroid.radius+radius) ,2))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function update(){

    if(leftKeyPressed == true){
        x-=5;
    }
    if(rightKeyPressed == true){
        x+=5;
    }

    if(x > 590){
        x = 0;
    }
    if(x < 0){
        x = 590;
    }

    for(let i = 0; i< astNumber; i++)
        asteroids[i].move();

    for(var i = 0; i< astNumber; i++)
        if(collision(asteroids[i])){
            dx = 0;
            dy = 0;
            x = 285;
            y = 394;
        }



    draw();
}

var leftKeyPressed =false;
var rightKeyPressed =false;
var spacePressed =false;



function keyDown(e){
    changeKey(e.keyCode, true);
}


function keyUp(e){
    changeKey(e.keyCode, false);
}

function changeKey(which, to){
    switch (which){
    case 32: spacePressed =to; break;
    case 37: leftKeyPressed =to; break;
    case 39: rightKeyPressed =to; break;
    }
}

window.onload=function(){
    ctx=document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
    document.onkeyup=keyUp;
    document.onkeydown=keyDown;
    timer = setInterval(update, 25);
};
```

[image]

For a number of days now I have been trying to create an array of Bullets that are fired when space is pressed, I am using an array because I would like a machine gun like affect(if there is an easier way of doing this without an array please explain). I have tried copying the asteroids code and tweaking it in many ways, in hope of achieving this. I am very new to coding and am unable to get this to work.

Here is the code I used when trying to get this to work.

```
    var ctx;
var timer = timer;

var x = 285;
var y = 394;
var radius = 25;
var dx=0;
var dy=0;
var shipX = x;
var fire = false;


var bulletImg = new Image();
bulletImg.src = "images/bullet.png";

function Bullet(x, y){
    this.x= shipX;
    this.y=394;
    this.radius = 10;
    this.fired = false;
    this.move = function(){
        this.y-=5;
    };
    this.drawBullet = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(bulletImg,this.x,this.y);
    };
}

var bullets = [];
var bulletNumber = 12;
for(var j = 0; j< bulletNumber; j++)
    bullets[j]= new Bullet();


function Machine(){
    if(fire==true){
        for(let j =0; j<bulletNumber;j++)
            bullets[j].fired=true;
        for(let j = 0; j< bulletNumber; j++)
            bullets[j].drawBullet(bullets);
        for(let j = 0; j< bulletNumber; j++)
            bullets[j].move();
        for(let j = 0; j< bulletNumber; j++)
            bullets[j].x=bullets[j].x;

    }
}

function reload(){
    for(var j = 0; j< bulletNumber; j++)
        if(bullets[j].y==394){
            bullets[j].x=shipX;
        }
    for(let j =0; j<bulletNumber;j++){
        bullets[j].fired=false;
    }
}




var asteroidImg = new Image();
asteroidImg.src = "images/asteroid.png";

function Asteroid(){
    this.x=Math.random()*600;
    this.y=Math.random()*600;
    this.radius = 10;
    this.dy=Math.random()*3+3;
    this.dx=0;
    this.move = function(){
        this.x= this.x + this.dx;
        this.y= this.y +this.dy;

        if(this.y>411){this.y = this.y=-10.;this.x=Math.random()*600;}

    };
    this.drawAsteroid = function (){
        ctx.drawImage(asteroidImg,this.x,this.y);
    };
}

var asteroids = [];
var astNumber = 10;
for(var i = 0; i< astNumber; i++)
    asteroids[i]=new Asteroid();

function drawAsteroids(asteroids){
    for(var i = 0; i< astNumber; i++){
        asteroids[i].drawAsteroid();
    }
}

var backgroundImg = new Image();
backgroundImg.src = "images/background.png";


var shipImg = new Image();
shipImg.src = "images/ship.png";



function drawShip(shipX,y){
    ctx.drawImage(shipImg,shipX, this.y);
}

function drawBackground(){
    ctx.drawImage(backgroundImg,0,0);
}


function draw(){
    drawBackground();
    drawShip(shipX,y);
    drawAsteroids(asteroids);
    Machine();
}

function collision(asteroid){
    if(Math.pow((asteroid.x-shipX) ,2)+Math.pow((asteroid.y-y) ,2)<Math.pow((asteroid.radius+radius) ,2))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function update(){

    if(leftKeyPressed == true){
        shipX-=5;
    }
    if(rightKeyPressed == true){
        shipX+=5;
    }


    if(spacePressed){
        fire=true;
    }

    if(spacePressed){
        if(keyUp){
            reload();

        }
    }

    if(x > 590){
        x = 0;
    }
    if(x < 0){
        x = 590;
    }

    for(let i = 0; i< astNumber; i++)
        asteroids[i].move();

    for(var i = 0; i< astNumber; i++)
        if(collision(asteroids[i])){
            dx = 0;
            dy = 0;
            x = 285;
            y = 394;
        }



    draw();
}


var leftKeyPressed =false;
var rightKeyPressed =false;
var spacePressed =false;


function keyDown(e){
    changeKey(e.keyCode, true);
}


function keyUp(e){
    changeKey(e.keyCode, false);
}

function changeKey(which, to){
    switch (which){
    case 32: spacePressed =to; break;
    case 37: leftKeyPressed =to; break;
    case 39: rightKeyPressed =to; break;
    }
}

window.onload=function(){
    ctx=document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
    document.onkeyup=keyUp;
    document.onkeydown=keyDown;
    timer = setInterval(update, 25);
};
```

When running this code all the bullets shoot at the same time when space is pressed and therefore it appears as if only one is being fired. I think to fix this bulletNumber would have to start at 1 and then increase, but I was unable to find a solution.

If you have any questions, would like me to clarify anything and or provide files so that you can run the code and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

On that line you have a typo:

```
        bullets[j].move;
```

should be

```
        bullets[j].move();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have changed it and am now given a "asteroid.js:109 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'move' of undefined" error.

Comment: Your mechanism for managing active bullets looks suspicious.  SO isn't the best way to debug this, at least not one-bug-at-a-time.  If you can put your app on jsfiddle, we may be able to help.

Comment: I tried creating a jsfiddle for you however I was unable to get it to work, here is the link with all the needed files if you would like to give it a go https://jsfiddle.net/dsbheycr/2/. I have done some more work in trying to get the bullets to work and will update my questions code after this comment. Maybe you can spot a problem now?

Comment: jsfiddle seemed to have trouble with the images.  I moved your app to repl.it:  https://repl.it/@jmbldwn/FakeIdioticOctal.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am very interested as to how this can be solved.(:

Comment: If you add a way to contact you to your profile, I'll see if I can reach out with a way to collaborate on this. (your reputation needs to be at least 20 to chat on SO)

Comment: I put a contact email in my profile. I also added my Twitter account if you would prefer to reach out on that.

Comment: Don't worry I've figured it out. Thanks heaps for your time.